# Add custom views besides Debug view or Full screen

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I noticed that Visual Studio can change the view settings for toolboxes and sizes when I go to Full Screen mode. In `normal` mode I can have the Solution view to the left of a certain width and the output window at the bottom.
In `Full Screen` view I can remove the toolboxes and see the design view only.

This is really useful for when I use it on a laptop for instance.

There is also a `Debug view`, which opens the Watch windows and Call stack..

Now, I would like a "Presentation View", so that I can easily switch between a bunch of toolboxes open, to only the solution view and design view. Can I define my own such views?